# Binding data inside an Adapter Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, android-databinding

I have created the adapter below which shows two different data models in the recycler view.

However, I am not sure how to do the bindings in the bind functions written in the ViewHolders. I have two seperate xml files which I would like to bind when this "bind" function is called but how do I set the data?

My code is as follows:

```
class HomeAdapter(
    private val context: Context
    ) :
    RecyclerView.Adapter<HomeAdapter.BaseViewHolder<*>>() {
    private var homeList: List<Any> = emptyList()

    companion object {
        private const val TYPE_VISIT = 0
        private const val TYPE_WASH = 1

    }

    abstract class BaseViewHolder<T>(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
        abstract fun bind(item: T)
    }

    inner class VisitViewHolder(itemView: View) : BaseViewHolder<HomeVisitLabel>(itemView) {

        override fun bind(item: HomeVisitLabel) {
            //Do your view assignment here from the data model
            
        }
    }

    inner class WashViewHolder(itemView: View) : BaseViewHolder<HomeWashLabel>(itemView) {

        override fun bind(item: HomeWashLabel) {
            //Do your view assignment here from the data model
        }
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): BaseViewHolder<*> {
        return when (viewType) {
            TYPE_VISIT -> {
                val view = LayoutInflater.from(context)
                    .inflate(R.layout.reward_label_visit_card, parent, false)
                VisitViewHolder(view)
            }
            TYPE_WASH -> {
                val view = LayoutInflater.from(context)
                    .inflate(R.layout.reward_label_wash_card, parent, false)
                WashViewHolder(view)
            }

            else -> throw IllegalArgumentException("Invalid view type")
        }
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: BaseViewHolder<*>, position: Int) {
        val element = homeList[position]
        when (holder) {
            is VisitViewHolder -> holder.bind(element as HomeVisitLabel)
            is WashViewHolder -> holder.bind(element as HomeWashLabel)
            else -> throw IllegalArgumentException()
        }
    }

    override fun getItemViewType(position: Int): Int {
        val comparable = homeList[position]
        return when (comparable) {
            is HomeVisitLabel -> TYPE_VISIT
            is HomeWashLabel -> TYPE_WASH
            else -> throw IllegalArgumentException("Invalid type of data " + position)
        }
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return homeList.size
    }


}
```

One of the two XML files

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <data>
        <variable
            name="VisitLabel"
            type="com.modelz.HomeVisitLabel" />

    </data>

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:cardCornerRadius="5dp"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/colorPrimary">



            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textSize="18sp"
                        android:text="Visit:"
                        android:gravity="left"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                        android:textStyle="bold"/>
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textSize="18sp"
                        android:text="@{VisitLabel.Name}"
                        android:gravity="left"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                        android:textStyle="bold"/>

                    <Button
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Redeem"
                        android:visibility="invisible"/>

                </LinearLayout>


                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:layout_weight="0.5"
                    android:gravity="left"
                    android:text="@{VisitLabel.descript}"
                    android:textSize="16dp" />


                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                        android:layout_weight="0.5"
                        android:gravity="left"
                        android:text="Progress:"
                        android:textSize="16dp" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                        android:layout_weight="0.9"
                        android:text="@{VisitLabel.countUser}"
                        android:gravity="right"
                        android:textSize="16sp" />
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                        android:layout_weight="0.5"
                        android:text="@{VisitLabel.countSet}"
                        android:gravity="left"
                        android:textSize="16sp" />

                </LinearLayout>

            </LinearLayout>

    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>



</layout>
```

Comment: You want to use two different data models in single adapter ?

Comment: So I assume you have two different DataBinding xml layouts. Why are you not using the generated Binding Class to inflate the view?

Comment: cewaphi I should inflate them using the Binding Class but I'm not sure how to do that?

Comment: @Ashish Yes, that is the issue I'm facing.

Comment: I have added 1 of the 2 XML files. They are basically the same, the other one just has an extra textView.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to use data binding, you need to inflate your layouts from `Binding` class as follow:

```
val binding = RewardLabelVisitCardBinding.inflate(layoutInflater, parent, false)
```

and same for the other layout.
You can get `layoutInflator` using:

```
val layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
```

And then in the `bind` function you need to use that `binding` variable to assign attributes. like,

```
binding.textView.text = item.name
```

The overall code for better understanding is given below:

```
class VisitViewHolder(private val binding: RewardLabelVisitCardBinding) : BaseViewHolder<HomeVisitLabel>(binding.root) {

    override fun bind(item: HomeVisitLabel) {
        binding.VisitLabel = item
        binding.executePendingBindings()
    }
}
```

Just pass `binding` variable to `ViewHolder` after inflating the layout in `onCreateViewHolder`

```
return VisitViewHolder(binding)
```

Hope, that answers your question!

Answer (score 0):

You will need to complete the bind functions for both the viewholders:

```
override fun bind(item: HomeVisitLabel) {
        // textView.text = item.name // example
    }
```

You should be able to assign the values in the function above as demonstrated by the example, this should work as in onBindViewHolder, the bind function is called depending on the type of data at the position in the array, allowing the data to be bound to different xml layout files.

You will have to complete the bind functions for both viewholders, setting text views to item data strings for example or setting images resources for image views, corresponding to the correct xml layout file for the data type.